# In shopify, how do I make refer to a specific instance of a Dynamic Section using CSS?

Tags: css, shopify, liquid

Dynamic Sections in shopify have dynamically generated ID's and Classes assigned during render. Since these may change from render to render, neither the ID nor the class can be used as CSS selectors. I would like to style a specific instance of a section which appears a few times on my page, but since they ave all been generated from the same template, the only differentiating selector is the dynamic ID and the dynamic Class. But these aren't static and are therefore risky. I haven't found any answer in the shopify documentation nor after talking to shopify support. Is there a method for targeting a specific instance of a dynamic section in CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Yes Shopify adds dynamic ids to sections, those ids are prefixed with `shopify-section-` and then have a number attached to them like `shopify-section-1582309868874`, however using this liquid code `shopify-section-{{ section.id }}` you should be able to re-generate that id.

You can also add unique class names to sections, those can be added in sections settings, example:

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Slideshow",
    "class": "slideshow-xyz"
  }
{% endschema %}
```

```html
<div id="shopify-section-[id]" class="shopify-section slideshow-xyz">
  [output of the section template]
</div>
```

[refe](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/develop-theme-use-sections#class)

To target a specific section in a page you'd add a `<style type="text/css">` inside the section – usually I'd add this after the markup and before section settings (aka `{% schema %}`) – and inside the `style` tag refer to the section id by it's dynamically generated id `#shopify-section-{{ section.id }}`, here is an example:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #shopify-section-{{ section.id }} {
    {% if section.settings.background_color != blank %}
      background-color: {{section.settings.background_color}};
    {% endif %}
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Karim/Dharman,
I'm not sure I follow you 100% though. If I add a class in the schema, then it will be added to all sections of that type (in your example, all slideshows), so then it wouldn't be unique. Am I wrong?
Also, it seems to me that having #shopify-section-{{ section.id }} in the template style will refer to every section the template renders, and the only specific qualifier for the unique sections instance is your "if" statement. Am I wrong?

Comment: Each section has a unique ID, there won't be two sections in the same page with the same ID, that's the point of an ID after all.

You are right about classes, this method it will only work for static sections that you add to pages other than home/index. For dynamic sections you can add an HTML wrapper around the section content with class name `<div class="shopify-section-{{ section.id }}">...</div>` however using the ID makes more sense to me in this case.